# Cannot print in awk command in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, printing

I am trying to read values from a file and print specific items into a variable which I will use later.

```bash
cat /dir1/file1 | while read blmbline2
do
    BLMBFILE2=`print $blmbline2 | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
    echo $BLMBFILE2
done
```

When I run that same code at the command line, it runs as expected, but, when I run it in a bash script called testme.sh, I get this error:

> ./testme.sh: line 3: print: command not found

If I run print by itself at the command prompt, I don't get an error (just a blank line).

If I run "bash" and then print at the command prompt, I get command not found.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Can someone suggest?

updated:  I see some other posts that say to use echo or printf?  Is there a difference I need to be concerned with in using one of those in bash?

Comment: Run `type print` from your command line and in the script so you can tell what you are using

Comment: thank you, I am converting print to echo and it's working.  Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

Since `awk` can read files, you may be able to do away with the `cat | while read` and just use `awk`.  Using a sample file containing:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Declare your bash array variable and populate with the output from `awk`:

```
arr=() ; arr=($(awk '{$1=""; print $0}' /dir1/file1))
```

Use the following to display array size and contents:

```
printf "array length: %d\narray contents: %s\n" "${#arr[@]}" "${arr[*]}"
```

Output:

```
array length: 30
array contents: 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `print` to `echo` in your shell script.  With `printf` you can format the data and with `echo` it will print the entire line of the file. Also, create an array so you can store multiple items:

```
BLMBFILE2=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'
do
  BLMBFILE2+=(`echo $REPLY | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`)
  echo $BLMBFILE2
done < <(cat /dir1/file1)

echo "Items found:"
for value in "${BLMBFILE2[@]}"
do
 echo $value
done
```

Comment: thanks - since I'm new, I can't upvote you yet, but yours is correct - I worked in parallel while waiting for an answer, converted print to echo and it works.  I always use echo, but this was code from someone else's script, so thought I had to make it work their way.  Thank you.

Comment: I just updated the answer to show how you should store items meeting your criteria in an array.  See the update code above.

Comment: BLMBFILE2 will be empty because subshell.

Comment: Thanks Kons! I forgeet about that..lol..I modified my code so it should return a value now.